# May I know how can I save post data to wordpress database from other php website

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have simple php website (non-wordpress site) and I want to save my posted data to my wordpress database table, Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you thinking of how to migrate the data from one db to the other, or how to send requests from non-wp site to wp site?

Comment: @Tami I'm talking about how to send requests from non-wp site to wp site :)

Comment: Cool! WordPress has exactly what you need for this, a REST API https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ Develop a custom rest endpoint that listens to requests from your non-wp site!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Be sure to check the documentation first before creating your own REST API endpoints though, there may be one already in place that you could use for whatever you need to do.

Comment: @Tami thanks tami.. can I call the wordpress api on my non-wordpress site via cURL? :)

Comment: Yeah, you just post to the correct endpoint. Depending on what you need to do (read or post) you will need to authenticate first.

Comment: What @cabrerahector says it's true, you don't necessarily need a custom endpoint, it depends on what you need to do

Comment: @Tami do you mean that I can reuse the function inside the wordpress? And I don't need to make a custom endpoint?

Comment: @RenzMarionRemias exactly. If you want to, for example, update/add Posts, you don't need a custom endpoint because WordPress already has an endpoint for this at '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'

Comment: @tami thanks man! what I target here is the contact form 7, I hope it has an endpoint already.

Comment: @RenzMarionRemias LOL I'm wo-man but thanks :) Check this out! https://github.com/CodeBradley/contact-form-7-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save post from another PHP site using this code

```
<?php
$username = 'adminusername';
$password = 'adminpassword';
$rest_api_url = "https://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";

$data_string = json_encode([
    'title'    => 'Your Title',
    'content'  =>  <<<HEREDOC
    
   
   Paste you content here
   

HEREDOC
,
    'status'   => 'publish',
]);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rest_api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password),
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($result) {
   echo 'yes';
} else {
  echo 'no';
    // ...
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks man! Is the username and password declared at the top the wordpress admin account?

Comment: Yes, its wp admin password

Comment: Thanks man! May I know if Contact Form 7 has REST API Endpoint for saving? I'm new to wordpress.